# C++ Asignar tamaño a un arreglo de una estructura

Tags: c++, array

Este es mi codigo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct nodos
{
    string nombre; //Nombre del nodo
    string vecinos[]; //Los otros nodos del grafo
    float aristas[]; //Valores de las aristas
};

int main()
{
    int numnodos;
    cout<<"Ingrese la cantidad de nodos a trabajar: ";
    cin>>numnodos;
    cout<<"\n";
    nodos arreglodenodos[numnodos]; //Declaro un arreglo de estructuras

    return 0;
}
```

Estoy haciendo un programa sobre grafos pero al querer programar los nodos (vertices) me he topado con el siguiente problema:

- Por ejemplo ingreso 5 en la cantidad de nodos a trabajar.
- Entonces el arreglo de estructuras ahora tendra un tamaño de 5.

  *pero aqui viene mi problema*
- Obviamente la cantidad de vecinos sera `numnodos-1`
- Pero no se como asignarle ese tamaño al arreglo `vecinos[]` asimismo con `aristas[]`

**PD:** como pregunta extra. ¿Sería mejor declarar nodos como un `class` o dejarla como una `struct`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin hacer muchos cambios a su codigo puede tratar lo siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <int N>
struct nodos
{
    string nombre; //Nombre del nodo
    string vecinos[N-1]; //Los otros nodos del grafo
    float aristas[N]; //Valores de las aristas
};

int main()
{
    int numnodos = 0;

    cout<<"Ingrese la cantidad de nodos a trabajar: ";
    cin>>numnodos;
    cout<<"\n";

    nodos<5> arreglodenodos[numnodos]; //Declaro un arreglo de estructuras

    //Solo para test
    cout<< "tamaño del array vecinos. " << endl;
    cout<< sizeof(arreglodenodos[1].vecinos)/sizeof(arreglodenodos[1].vecinos[0]) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Usamos `template <int N>` y lo empleamos asi:

```
nodos<5> arreglodenodos[numnodos];
```

Donde 5 es la cantidad que se usa para el template. Fijese que `N` se usa dentro de la struct para asignar el tamaño `string vecinos[N-1];` o `float aristas[N];`.

Lo que esta bajo `// Solo para test`, no es relevante en su pregunta, esta linea:

`sizeof(arreglodenodos[1].vecinos)/sizeof(arreglodenodos[1].vecinos[0])`

es para calcular el tamaño.

<kbd>[ideone](https://ideone.com/DBaosl)</kbd>

---

Otra manera si la constante es un problema seria la siguiente, pero tiene que hacer unos cambios:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


struct nodos
{
    string nombre; 

    std::vector<string> vecinos; //<- cambio a std:vector
    std::vector<float> aristas;  //<- cambio a std:vector

    nodos(int N){                //<- cambio se añade constructor

        vecinos.resize(N -1);
        aristas.resize(N);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int numnodos = 0;

    cout<<"Ingrese la cantidad de nodos a trabajar: ";
    cin>>numnodos;
    cout<<"\n";

    nodos arreglodenodos[numnodos](numnodos); //<- Aqui hacemos uso del constructor

    //Solo para test
    cout<< arreglodenodos[1].vecinos.size();

    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[ideone](https://ideone.com/XFRo8c)</kbd>

---

[std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) info:

Comment: gracias Angel, de hecho le implemente vectores y funciona mucho mejor, aunque probare lo de las template, no manejo aun ese tema, pero lo probare a ver que tal

Answer (score 0):

yo utilizaria las clases y listas(en vez de arr) para este trabajo ya q deberia existir un obj arista ya que esta es la q indica cuales son los nodos q estan relacionados y el nodo indica cuales son las aristas q los relacionan, algo asi:

class Node {
  String nombre;
  List list_arista;
//Constructor , get and set
  ...
}
class Arista{
  String valor;
  Node n1;
  Node n2;
}

Comment: no estaria mal, de hecho pense en esa solucion primero, pero te tocaria hacer mas objetos has de cuenta creas 4 nodos y tendras que hacer 6 aristas, cuando en los nodos pudiste declarar las aristas de una vez

Comment: es cierto pero a veces lo facil al final no cuesta y creo q eso es lo q te pasa.Si lo haces con obj creo q el trabajo te va salir mas facil